# Confused with shared preferences file names to exclude automatic backup

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm a bit confused on how shared preferences file names work. I'm not sure if any naming prefix or sufixes are implicitly added.

Will the backup.xml file below exclude all "myCustomPref" items from automatic backup?

backup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="myCustomPref"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

This is how I declare my backup.xml file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MRApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup"
    ...
```

This is how I declare the shared pref file:

```
SharedPreferences settings = activity.getSharedPreferences("myCustomPref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("myData", value);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
 <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="myCustomPref"/>
```

Do :

```
 <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="myCustomPref.xml"/>
```